# React material design function call automatically on page onload instead on onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using the React material design library.  I added an `onClick` listener to `<link>`, but the function is called on a page load.  Why is this happening?

Here is my code :

```
<Link onClick={openBrowserWindow('http://www.stackoverflow.com')}/>

const openBrowserWindow = (url) =>{
   fin.desktop.system.openUrlWithBrowser(url);
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way you put the onCLick method, the function call it itself

try put the call into a function

```
<Link onClick = {()=>openBrowserWindow('stackoverflow.com')}/>
```